# Simple PHP Logout Function, Doesn't Work Until I Leave the Page

Tags: php, cookies, session-cookies, logout

I'm trying to implement a simple PHP logout script. I have the below code. When logged in and I click on a link that redirects to the logout script, it doesn't seem to realize I'm logged out and still displays the same information. However, once I close the tab, and re-open it, it no longer shows me the same information. Any ideas?

```
session_start();
session_destroy();
unset($_COOKIE['cookie_name']);
setcookie("cookie_name", "", time()-3600);
header("Location: http://mydomain.com/");
exit();
```

Comment: Have your tried the example on the `session_destroy` help page: http://au1.php.net/session_destroy

Comment: Whats the 'information' you see when logged in? what you dont want to see in logged out?

Comment: @Renku I right now simply have a script that uses the cookie value to identify a user and displays their name. Ideally, when logged out, it should disappear (I have my code set as such).

Comment: @Ben just tried that, no luck :/

Comment: Try answer by Nanhe below, if it doesnot help use SESSION variables instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is perfect but if you are facing some problem then please use this code when you are setting cookies.

```
setcookie("cookie_name", "", time()+3600,"/", "mydomain.com", 1);

session_destroy();
unset($_COOKIE['cookie_name']);
setcookie("cookie_name", "", time()-3600,"/", "mydomain.com", 1);

header("Location: http://mydomain.com/");
exit();
```

Are you using both session and cookies?

Comment: Hi, I've been using only cookies, I included the session stuff in the script for the sake of future use. I'll let you know once I try this out.

Answer (score 0):

If you are unfortunate with cookies,

Use the code in `http://mydomain.com/`

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['uname']=$username;
echo $_SESSION['uname'];
```

Use this in Logout

```
session_start();
session_destroy();
header("Location: http://mydomain.com/");
```

Instead.